# Double Numerical Integral - precision is not improving answer

Tags: numerical-integration, precision-and-accuracy

Consider this two-dimensional integral

```
 NIntegrate[
 r^3 4^a/ ((1 + r^2 - 2 r Cos[s])^4)
      ChebyshevU[b, -((-1 + r)/Sqrt[1 + r^2 - 2 r Cos[s]])] ((
     1 + r - 2 Sqrt[r] Cos[s/2])/Sqrt[1 + r^2 - 2 r Cos[s]])^
    a If[1 + r^2 - 2 r Cos[s] < 1 && 
      1 - r Cos[s] < 4/
       5 && (r^2 > 1 || 1/2 > r Cos[s] || r Cos[s] > 4/5), 1, 0] Sin[
     s]^2  , {r, 0, ∞}, {s, 0, π}]
```

which I would like to integrate for various values of $a$ and $b$.

If I compute this integral with WorkingPrecision->15 for $b=0,a=4$, then I get 13.9927829 with error 0.0177517. Similarly, for $b=10,a=20$ I get -0.212035 with error 0.003404. In both cases, if I improve the WorkingPrecision, PrecisionGoal, and/or AccuracyGoal (which are the usual tricks I know that help reduce error) though, then the error does not decrease! The problem does not seem to be oscillations, as the same problem occurs for both $b=0$ and $b=10$, and I do not think the integrand oscillates when $b=0$ (even though it might when $b=10$ due do the Chebyshev polynomial).

How can I improve the integral such that I can get arbitrary accurate results for any reasonable (i.e. not huge) value of $a,b\geq0$ (even if I have to wait longer to get more accuracy, I don't mind that)?

Comment: With respect to what is or is not oscillating, do you mean the integrand or the integral? (It cannot be the integral, I think, since it is a number, not a function.)  My plots of the integrand look nothing like the plots above.

Comment: `WorkingPrecision->15` is not going to improve your answers. You are probably confusing `WorkingPrecision` with `PrecisionGoal`. Voting to close.

Comment: RE Michael E2: when i talk about oscillations, i am of course talking about the integrand (how could an integral be oscillating?!), and these are plots of the integrand. how could you be plotting the integral for $b=0, a=4$?

Comment: Re Anton^2: please read my question more carefully before commenting. i said that i first computed it with WorkingPrecision->15, and then increased the WorkingPrecision to much greater values, and saw no improvement. In general, increasing PrecisionGoal does nothing with the same WorkingPrecision, if the integral has not already obtained the minimum Precision goal (as i specified in the question, my integrals have barely a few digits of precision already!)

Comment: Re Michael E2: i saw that i made a typo in the original question talking about oscillating integrals instead of integrands, i now corrected it.

Comment: guys, why has this question been put as off-topic? this is a challenging integral that i have been unable to get anything more than a few digits of accuracy. have you guys been able to improve the precision? none of the suggestions so far have resolved my problem...

Comment: [Site tip: Use @user to notify the users of your reply comment.] I can improve the integral that's posted, but, what I said before, "My plots of the integrand look nothing like the plots above." I don't want to write up an answer only to have you tell me that you made a mistake with the integrand. Could you post the codes you used for the plots, so I can compare them to the integral?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks for the commenting tip. I had forgotten to put the If statement in the plots, after adding that statement the plots are kinda hard to glean anything from, so I removed them (i dont think they add to the question anyway). also, i was missing a factor of $4^a$ in the integrand (which doesn't really affect anything). The main problem (which hopefully the question emphasizes now) is that the usual tricks of increasing PrecisionGoal, AccuracyGoal, and WorkingPrecision does not actually improves the integral.

Comment: `integrand = 4^a r^3/((1+r^2-2r Cos[s])^4)ChebyshevU[b, -((-1+r)/Sqrt[1+r^2-2r Cos[s]])] ((1+r-2Sqrt[r]Cos[s/2])/Sqrt[1+r^2-2rCos[s]])^a Sin[s]^2; wp = MachinePrecision; wp = 24; pg = wp/2.6; toNInt[_[s1_,___,s2_] && _[r1_,___,r2_]] := NIntegrate[integrand, {s,s1,s2}, {r,r1,r2}, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp]; Block[{b = 10, a = 20, echo}, subintegrals = Replace[Reduce[(1+r^2-2r Cos[s] < 1 && 1-r Cos[s] < 4/5 && (r^2 > 1 || 1/2 > r Cos[s] || r Cos[s] > 4/5)) && 0 < s < Pi && r > 0, {r}], HoldPattern@Or[i__] :> toNInt /@ {i}]; integral = SetPrecision[subintegrals, pg] // Total]`

Comment: The previous comment gives the basic idea...will post if Q is reopened.

Comment: **1.** "please read my question more carefully before commenting [...]" -- I did.  **2.** "[...] i said that i first computed it with WorkingPrecision->15, and then increased the WorkingPrecision..." -- No, you did not say that in your first version of the post, to which I commented.

Comment: @AntonAntonov I did change the question to remove the plots, but from the very beginning I specified quite clearly that the integral was not improving with improving precision. Anyway, if you weren't sure what I was saying, why not ask me, instead of uniliterally closing this question, and thus making it harder for other people to help me? anyway, now that I've clarified this, can you please either give useful help, or at the very least reopen this question so that others can help me?

Comment: @MichaelE2 thanks for that comment, but its a bit hard to understand what ur saying and it would be more useful as a conventional answer. How do I reopen this question? Should I just delete this entire question and ask it again? Also, it is common stackexchange practice to close questions within minutes without trying to first clarify with the OP? that seems unhelpful to me...

Comment: The OP had incorporated substantial additions into his question and the post already had 3 reopening votes. And although I am aware that this is a dangerous business nowadays, I will abuse my power as a mod and re-open it :)

Comment: @MichaelE2 thanks for all the help! You should be able to post your answer now...

Comment: "Anyway, if you weren't sure what I was saying, why not ask me, instead of uniliterally closing this question,[...]" -- I cannot "unilaterally" close or open a question, it takes at least 3 other votes for both. (Or just a moderator.) And it seems to me that process worked as designed -- the closing votes indicated to you that something might be wrong with your formulations, and after your clarifications the question is reopened.

Comment: @MichaelE2 could you expand on your answer in the comments? I was unable to follow it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Code, with updated `Reduce[]` and integration `Method`:

```
integrand = 4^a r^3/((1 + r^2 - 2 r Cos[s])^4) *
   ChebyshevU[b, -((-1 + r)/Sqrt[1 + r^2 - 2 r Cos[s]])] *
   ((1 + r - 2 Sqrt[r] Cos[s/2])/Sqrt[1 + r^2 - 2 r Cos[s]])^a *
   (*Boole[1+r^2-2 r Cos[s]<1 && 1-r Cos[s]<4/5 && (r^2>1 || 1/2>r Cos[s] || r Cos[s]>4/5)]*)
   Sin[s]^2;
wp = MachinePrecision; (* set working precision *)
wp = 24;               (* set working precision *)
pg = wp/2.9;           (* set precision goal *)
toNInt[_[s1_, ___, s2_] && _[r1_, ___, r2_]] := (* integrate over a region *)
  NIntegrate[integrand, {s, s1, s2}, {r, r1, r2},
   PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp,
   Method -> {"MultidimensionalRule", "Generators" -> 9}];
PrintTemporary@Dynamic@{foo = Clock[Infinity]};  (* monitors time *)
Block[{b = 10, a = 20, echo},
  echo = (Print[foo, ": integrating ", #]; #) &; (* prints time each integral starts *)
  subintegrals = Replace[
    Reduce[#, r] & /@ 
     BooleanConvert@
      Reduce[(1 + r^2 - 2 r Cos[s] < 1 && 
          1 - r Cos[s] <  4/5 &&
          (r^2 > 1 || 1/2 > r Cos[s] || r Cos[s] > 4/5)) && 
        0 < s < Pi && r > 0, {r}, Reals],
    HoldPattern@Or[i__] :> toNInt@*echo /@ {i}
    ];
  integral = SetPrecision[subintegrals, pg] // Total;
  integralprec = Precision[integral];
  {integral, integralprec}
  ] // AbsoluteTiming
(*
  0.335269: integrating 0<s<ArcCos[4/5]&&Sec[s]/5<r<Sec[s]/2

  0.335269: integrating 0<s<ArcCos[4/5]&&(4 Sec[s])/5<r<2 Cos[s]

  0.335269: integrating ArcCos[4/5]<=s<π/3&&1<r<2 Cos[s]

  0.335269: integrating π/3<=s<ArcCos[1/Sqrt[10]]&&Sec[s]/5<r<2 Cos[s]

  0.335269: integrating ArcCos[4/5]<=s<π/3&&Sec[s]/5<r<Sec[s]/2

Out[]=
  {0.427674, {-0.02578, 3.90475}}
*)
```

Here are the results for increasing working precision. One can infer the accuracy of a previous result by comparing how many digits agree with the subsequent results.  `MachinePrecision` results are obtained quickly, but increasing `WorkingPrecision` rapidly slows down the computation.

```
{time,
 {integral,                      pg}}

{0.427674`,                      (* wp=MachinePrecision *)
 {-0.0257816408128350764,        3.9047482670549747`}}
           ^ 6 digits of precision > pg=3.9
{4.366194`,                      (* wp=24 *)
 {-0.0257816195648316161,        6.679027290327976`}}
              ^ 9 digits of precision > pg=6.7
{94.906609`,                     (* wp=36 *)
 {-0.025781619559796699077118,   10.816958324724922`}}
                    ^ 15 digits of precision > pg=10.8
{369.352305`,                    (* wp=42 *)
 {-0.025781619559796682025612,   12.885923841966303`}}
```

The domain of integration defined by `If[cond, 1, 0]` can be broken down by `Reduce` into component subregions, if we solve for `r` in terms of `s` (indicated by the order of the variables `{s, r}` in the second argument of `Reduce[]`).
It splits the domain into five subregions:

```
regs = Reduce[(1 + r^2 - 2 r Cos[s] < 1 && 
    1 - r Cos[s] < 4/5 &&
    (r^2 > 1 || 1/2 > r Cos[s] || r Cos[s] > 4/5)) && 
  0 < s < Pi && r > 0, {r}]
(*
(0 < s < ArcCos[4/5] && Sec[s]/5 < r < Sec[s]/2) ||
 (0 < s < ArcCos[4/5] && (4 Sec[s])/5 < r < 2 Cos[s]) ||
 (ArcCos[4/5] <= s < π/3 && 1 < r < 2 Cos[s]) ||
 (π/3 <= s < ArcCos[1/Sqrt[10]] && Sec[s]/5 < r < 2 Cos[s]) ||
 (ArcCos[4/5] <= s < π/3 && Sec[s]/5 < r < Sec[s]/2)
*)

Show[
 RegionPlot[regs,
  {s, 0, Pi/2}, {r, 0, 2.5}],
 ContourPlot[Evaluate@DeleteDuplicates@Flatten@Cases[regs,
      HoldPattern@Inequality[x1_, _, x_, _, x2_] | 
        Less[x1_, x_, x2_] :> {x == x1, x == x2}, Infinity],
  {s, 0, Pi/2}, {r, 0, 2.5}]
 ]
```

[image]

The function `toNInt` converts a subregion into a call to `NIntegrate`.  The code assumes the output of `Reduce` is in form shown above.

Comment: Have to go to my real job now. Will respond to queries when I have the time.

Comment: Wow this is super useful! If I understand correctly, the main advantage of your method is that NIntegrate is sampling points ONLY within the region of the integral, whereas in my naive method i was telling Mathematica to integrate everywhere in r,s, but then afterward putting an If statement in the integrand so in practice only a small percentage of sampling points where actually being used?

Comment: @esches Yes, when sampling points cross a boundary, it adds a large amount to the error estimation.  `NIntegrate` has to work much harder to refine the sampling around the boundaries to get the error within goals.

Comment: I think there might be a small mistake with your answer. When you do reduce to get 4 regions, the last two regions are overlapping, so your integral is double counting. You can fix this for the fourth region by adding the condition $r<1$. do you agree?

Comment: @esches Oops, you're right.  I didn't realize `Reduce` would produce overlapping regions.  It works if the domain `Reals` is specified.  I'll update with the accurate results when it's done running.

Comment: @MichaelE2 There seems to be a comma missing in your code after `PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp` within the `toNInt` function. I apologise, I was not sure how to alert an author of such a minor edit.

Comment: @cphys Thanks.  You could also just edit such corrections.